# Cloud run service deleted but the website is still running

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have deployed a containerized website with Cloud Run on GCP. The URL is something like this **https://my-website-kjasd8hd81-sad.a.run.app**.
I don't need it anymore and I deleted it. But when I access the URL again, the website is still there.

Does anyone know how to completely delete the website?

Comment: Hello, Have you followed this [document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/managing/services) to delete the Cloud Run Service. And there might be a chance that the issue seems to be with Google's cache. Catching is the process of storing information for a set period of time on a computer. Invalidate the cache and try to access the URL, it may not work.

Comment: You should have cache. The website is no longer available

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni I followed the document. How can I invalidate the cache? I delete the service for a week but it's still there

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere do you know how to clear the cache?

Comment: @Quyết, You can do it by following the steps in the [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) and have you tried to access the URL in other System.